# react/no-typos rule throw an error when declare a property as style

Tags: reactjs, npm, ecmascript-2016

I'm declaring styles property for my component. It looks like:

```js
  MoodImage.propTypes = {
    moodId: PropTypes.number,
    comment: PropTypes.string,
    style: PropTypes.style,
  };
```

and I'm getting the following errors:

> Line 40:  Typo in declared prop type: style  react/no-typos
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

i've read something about ES7 syntax but i don't know how to update this sentence. may you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I do not think there is a `PropTypes.style` type.

Comment: try changing it to `PropTypes.object`